# How to get Security update only for window 10 and server 2019?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, wsus, windows-server-2019

So previously for Win7 and servers up to 2012R, we push out [Security Monthly Quality Roll up ] updates, looks like they are no longer available for Windows 10 and Server 2019?

What is the current Windows update module for Win10 and Server2019, I was searching these update package in  [Microsoft®Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx) and there is no results returned about Win10 and Server2019.

Have the update model changed already?

Comment: There isn't a security-only update. It changed six years ago.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows update module for Win10 and Server2019 update please refer below link :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/security-update-for-windows-10-version-1607-1703-1709-1803-1809-1903-1909-windows-server-2016-and-windows-server-2019-february-11-2020-755ab061-817d-144b-e4de-2c4ee4f1d596

https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/